# Move blocks in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAB1L.jpg)I want to move these blocks in the centre of the page.I have used html and tailwind css.I have tried justify-centre but its not working. please help.Here's the html code.[

```html
<main>
        <div class="justify-center items-center">
            <div class="bg-blue-200 py-20 text-center">
                <!-- grid -->
                
                <div class="flex">
                    <div>
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
                    <div>
        
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
                        <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

[image]

Comment: you have to add "flex" class to the same div where you have justify-center. If you don't want to make it flex, you can use mx-auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add justify-center to the class where whole blocks have parent div, that is line number 4

```
 <main>
  <div class="justify-center items-center">
    <div class="bg-blue-200 py-20 text-center">
      <!-- grid -->

      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div>
          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>

          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>

          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>

          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>

          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>

          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>
          <div class="cursor-pointer bg-slate-500 h-20 w-20 border-blue-200 border"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image]